# Log4J2 AsyncLogger is filling up LMAX disruptor's ring buffer at high concurrency

Tags: java, logging, playframework, configuration, log4j2

I am using Log4J2 AsyncLogger in my Java Play Framework based application. I see that at high concurrency (~3000 users per server) the ring buffer's remaining size reaches zero quickly and my requests start to fail. My ring buffer size is 1048576 (512*2048). The number of application threads are 8 (1 thread per core as stated in Play's official documentation.)
My questions are:

1> How can I increase the speed at which the consumer writes to the log file?
2> Can I explicitly use multiple consumers to write to my log file? If so, where do I specify these consumers?

I have included my log4j2.xml file. Any help will be highly appreciated :)

Things I tried:

1> Increased ring buffer size (always as a power of 2). But eventually the same problem arises, and using too much memory does not seem very elegant. This option will be shot down in production. Am I missing anything?

2> Tried different waiting strategies. No luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration>
<!--  status="trace" attribute for Configuration tag prints in logs [ Starting AsyncLoggerConfig disruptor for this configuration with ringbufferSize=262144] -->
<!-- default log file names in case it fails to read it from property file -->
<Properties>
    <Property name="FILE_NAME">/opt/lol/logs/meh.log</Property>
    <Property name="FILE_PATTERN">/opt/lol/logs/meh_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="ASYNCFILE" fileName="${sys:FILE_NAME}" filePattern="${sys:FILE_PATTERN}">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[meh:%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss},%d{SSS}] %-5level[%thread][%C{1}:%L] %msg%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </Policies>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>

    <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[meh:%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss},%d{SSS}] %-5level[%thread][%C{1}:%L] %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <logger name="akka" level="INFO" />
    <AsyncRoot level="INFO" includeLocation="true">
       <!-- <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>-->
        <AppenderRef ref="ASYNCFILE"/>
    </AsyncRoot>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I expect the concurrency to hit at least 4000 per box (the same as without loggers). But I am stuck at around 2500.

Comment: Could you tell me how to know the ring buffer's remaining size reaches zero? I just configured log4j with async mode, but do not know how ring buffer has been used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You can increase the speed by not using location: replace `[%C{1}:%L]` with simply `%c`. The Log4j 2 [performance documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html#asyncLoggingWithLocation) shows that logging location is 100x slower.
2. Multiple consumers will not speed up logging. The hard disk is still the single end-consumer and having multiple threads trying to write at the same time (using locking to prevent data corruption) is actually slower. This is why the disruptor is designed the way it is.

Comment: Thanks Remko! At this point of time due to development constraints we need to keep the location. If we follow the route you suggested, then we need to change every log message in our application so that it also prints the class name in which it is present. For now, is there an alternate way to improve performance? Maybe not 100x, but still something significant?

Comment: No you shouldn’t have change your code. How do you create a Logger in your code? If you create them the “standard” way: `private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();` then the name of each logger is the fully qualified class name where the logger is declared.  Therefore, `%c` (lowercase) will show the class that does the logging. Usually log messages are unique enough that you can tell from the log message which logging statement in your code generated the message, so I’ve never had a need for location. (Currently Log4j is creating a stack trace for _every single log message_...)

Comment: Thank you so much! That did give a noticeable performance increase. I also noted that using memory mapped files gives a HUGE boost to performance, but takes a considerable amount of time to be written to disk. Also, the memory mapped file cannot be tailed. Are memory mapped files eventually consistent? If I use them in production, do they guarantee that their contents will be written to disk at some point? In that case, we can look at using these in our system.

Comment: Yes, with memory mapped files the OS is responsible for flushing the memory to disk so even if the Java process crashes the logs will make it to the disk. However, if you log so much that you fill up your physical memory, your box may freeze for multiple minutes while the OS works overtime to write the memory content to disk. (I experienced this once and wasn’t even able to login to the machine for 10 minutes. Once the memory was written to disk everything resumed...) So there are trade offs to be aware of.

Comment: @remko: lets say 1. we have appropriate archival policies so disk space is never under pressure. 2. We are ok with delayed tailing or delayed showing of logs in splunk etc. Then it seems a no brainer that we should be using mmap files for logging. Am surprised why most production systems do not use mmap files for logging. The performance difference is huge. In fact, what we found was that the performance seems to be almost as good as when totally disabling logs.

Comment: Although it is more expensive, if your application is going to be that I/O intensive you might consider using SSDs for the log files. 

If the memory mapped appender works for you go for it. Just be aware of the limitations documented at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html under "Trade Offs"

Comment: It’s been 5+ years since I did performance testing with the mmapped appender, but I remember results were very inconsistent at the time. RandomAccessFile appender with a decent buffer size was only slightly slower but much more consistent. One drawback of memory mapped files: remapping is slow (have you measured performance when logging more than the size of the mapped region?)

Comment: @RemkoPopma: In log4j2 we have multiple producers writing to the ring buffer and a single consumer pulling them and writing them to a file. In this case, how are the log events get arranged chronologically while being written to the disk?